# Forking Django DB connections

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an application which receives data over a TCP connection and writes it to a postgres database. I then use a django web front end to provide a gui to this data. Since django provides useful database access methods my TCP receiver also uses the django models to write to the database.

My issue is that I need to use a forked TCP server. Forking results in both child and parent processes sharing handles. I've read that Django does not support forking and indeed the shared database connections are causing problems e.g. these exceptions:

DatabaseError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac

InterfaceError: connection already closed

What is the best solution to make the forked TCP server work?

- Can I ensure the forked process uses its own database connection?
- Should I be looking at other modules for writing to the postgres database?

Comment: What problem exactly are you solving with forking?

Comment: The main reason for me is speed and resilience. This server is handling large volumes of data and thread switching is a limit at the minute. Multiprocess means no GIL issues (I know socket operations release the GIL while they block but post processing can only happen in one thread at a time).

Comment: I would use green threads via eventlet or gevent unless you are seriously CPU-limited.  Both eventlet and gevent have mechanisms to make Postgres play nice with many concurrent connections.  Is that an option?

Answer (score 1):

So one solution I found is to create a new thread to spawn from. Django opens a new connection per thread so spawning from a new thread ensures you pass a new connection to the new process.

In retrospect I wish I'd used psycopg2 directly from the beginning rather than Django. Django is great for the web front end but not so great for a standalone app where all I'm using it for is the model layer. Using psycopg2 would have given be greater control over when to close and open connections. Not just because of the forking issue but also I found Django doesn't keep persistent postgres connections - something we should have better control of in 1.6 when released and should for my specific app give a huge performance gain. Also, in this type of application I found Django intentionally leaks - something that can be fixed with DEBUG set to False. Then again, I've written the app now :)

Answer (score 0):

The `libpq` driver, which is what the `psycopg2` driver usually used by django is built on, does not support forking an active connection. I'm not sure if there might be another driver does not, but I would assume not - the protocol does not support multiplexing multiple sessions on the same connection.

The proper solution to your problem is to make sure each forked processes uses its own database connection. The easiest way is usually to wait to open the connection until after the fork.

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to ensure each forked process uses its own database connection. I have one specific case where database connections are opened necessarily before a fork. I think the answer is going to be to use psycopg2 directly so that I can explicitly control this rather than let Django manage the connections.